# How to boot htc desire ss510e into recovery

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, updates

I want to install 4.0 ics on my htc desire ss510e, so i want to know how can i boot into recovery in order to install the custom firmware. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Boot up your phone using **power button and volume down button** together. You'll get something called hboot. Now using your volume buttons, goto **Recovery Mode** listed on the screen. Press the trackpad button to reach recovery mode.